# How do I join the most recent row in one table to another table MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 tables

First is

**addresses**
*id                   ad                               datetime

1          121.252.212.121        2015-04-20 08:23:04

2              121.252.212.122             2015-05-20 09:11:06

3              121.252.212.121           2015-05-20 11:56:04

4          121.252.212.123            2015-05-20 09:54:25

5            121.252.212.123            2015-05-20 10:23:04

6            121.252.212.122           2015-05-20 09:50:10

7           121.252.212.123            2015-05-20 12:50:02*

Second is

**monitor**
server_id                 ad                                            label
*1                         121.252.212.121                          North

2                          121.252.212.122                           South

3                         121.252.212.123                             East*

i use this query

SELECT monitor.label, addresses.datetime
FROM monitor
INNER JOIN addresses
ON monitor.ad=addresses.ad
ORDER BY monitor.label;

**MYOUTPUT**

label                                datetime
North                    2015-04-20 08:23:04
North                    2015-05-20 11:56:04
South                    2015-05-20 09:11:06
South                    2015-05-20 09:50:10
East                       2015-05-20 09:54:25
East                       2015-05-20 10:23:04
East                       2015-05-20 12:50:02

but my desire output is to get the recent row and merge duplicate label
example below

**MYDESIRE**
label                   datetime
North                         2015-05-20 11:56:04
South                        2015-05-20 09:50:10
East                          2015-05-20 12:50:02

anyone can help me on this matter?

NOTE* addresses AD is not primary or unique
      but monitor AD is Primary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [`mysql group-wise maximum`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) and there are many ways of doing it and one way is

```
select 
m.label, 
a.datetime from monitor m 
join ( 
 select ad, max(datetime) as datetime from addresses group by ad
)a on a.ad = m.ad;
```

Comment: Hi sir another question what if i want query within date and time

ex, 

today time is 10am i want to query 10am to 11am withing the  current date

Comment: Just add a where clause inside the inner query as `select ad, max(datetime) as datetime from addresses where datetime between concat(curdate(),' ','10:00:00') and concat(curdate(),' ','11:00:00') group by ad`

Comment: Hi sir sorry i mean 

current time and 1 hr ahead.

ex.
 today datetime is 6/4/2015 10am i only want to query who have datetime between 10am-11am of 6/4/2015


so if I check again on 
datetime  6/4/2015 3pm i only want to query who have datetime between 3pm-4pm of 6/4/2015

Comment: You may do as `where datetime between now() and date_add(now(),interval 1 hour)`

Comment: Hi sir so my query should be like this??

select 
m.label, 
a.datetime from monitor_servers m 
join ( 
 select ad, max(datetime) as datetime from addresses where datetime between now() and date_add(now(),interval 1 hour) group by ad)a on a.ad = m.ad

Comment: Its difficult to guess without seeing the data, make sure you have data falling in the date range that you are specifying.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `group by` and `max`:

```
SELECT monitor.label, max(addresses.datetime) 
FROM monitor INNER JOIN addresses ON monitor.ad=addresses.ad 
group by monitor.label 
ORDER BY monitor.label;
```

Comment: Max does not gurantee of returning same row while joining the table.

Comment: Abhik, luckily the op only wants two columns

Comment: Hi another question that i want to query the data on this current date and time and 1hr ahead

ex.

today datetime is 6/4/2015 10am

i only want to query who have datetime
between 10am-11am of 6/4/2015

Comment: @CarlvicJapitanaLim Try `where datetime between now() and DATE_ADD(now() ,HOUR)`

Answer (score 0):

Use a `GROUP BY` Clause.

```
SELECT label, MAX(datetime)
FROM monitor INNER JOIN addresses
ON monitor.ad = addresses.ad
GROUP BY label
```